# Is fzero in the standard MATLAB package or is it part of the optimization package?

Tags: matlab

Is fzero in the standard MATLAB package or is it part of the optimization package?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's in both, but the supported arguments between them differ.  You can compare at their respective documentation pages:

- [`fzero` (Standard Package)](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/fzero.html)
- [`fzero` (Optimization Toolbox)](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/optim/ug/fzero.html)

Answer (score 2):

Can't it be both?  ([standard](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/fzero.html), with [optimization extensions](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/optim/ug/fzero.html)?)

A quick comparison shows that the optimization extension can take a "problem" input.